# Header issue when combing two existing C++ programs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, forward-declaration

I have a program that I have written in C++ that compiles and works fine. I am trying to combine this with another C++ program that uses my program as a function.

And what I have done is to put my program in as the fitness function of their program. The programs have layouts like this:

http://s23.postimg.org/s3fbqsn0b/Together.png

The problem is when I try to compile this, I get a lots of errors:
"x already defined in Old_Main.Obj"

So someone told me about forward declaring the function and NOT including the A2.h in B.Cpp. When I try to compile this with gcc I get:
"undefined reference to x"

Comment: Don't put object or function definitions in headers. Only put object and function *declarations* in headers and put the corresponding definition in a single, separate translation unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you set up the project:

In *one* header goes the *prototype* for x:

```
void x(int);
```

*All* the .cpp files include that header.

*One* .cpp file defines x:

```
void x(int alpha)
{
...
}
```

When you build the project the linker will find your definition of x and resolve all the calls to it.

Comment: I have created the prototype for the function old_main and put it in the header old_main.h. This header is then included in the cpp which calls old_main, however I still receive the error "undefined reference to old_main"

Comment: Is that a compile error or a link error? Post the code where the error happens and also the text of the error.

Comment: I have added it all to the original post (is that right?)

Comment: It's a linker error, meaning that your code compiled OK. You are not providing the definition for the function with the signature PN(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >) . Since it compiled OK then we know that you provided the prototype for the function but somewhere in the source code there needs to be the definition for the function. I guess the question is "what .ccp file contains the function with that signature?" When you answer that you can look at the make file and see why that .cpp file isn't where it needs to be.

Comment: That definition of that function is provided in another cpp file. When I use the intel compiler it works fine. It just seems to be giving me an error when i try to use the make file (GCC compiler). The problem is I didnt make the make file and it is very complex.

Comment: I think , based on your previous comment, that the issue is in the make file. I assume that using Intel compiler involves a different build process that does use that make file?